# Multiple regression function does not work in R

Tags: r, function, regression

I am trying to get the below piece of code to work - which performs multiple regression with different stepwise methods i.e. backward, forward, exhaustive, seqrep, but it is returning an error at the method = stepwise line.

```
# cross-validation
predict.regsubsets <- function(object, newdata, id, ...) {

  form  = as.formula(object$call[[2]])
  mat   = model.matrix(form, newdata)
  coefs = coef(object, id = id)
  xvars = names(coefs)

  mat[, xvars] %*% coefs
}

rmse <- function(actual, predicted) {
  sqrt(mean((actual - predicted) ^ 2))
}    

cv <- function(stepwise, folds) {
      num_folds = folds

      set.seed(1)
      folds = caret::createFolds(mtcars$mpg, k = num_folds)
      fold_error = matrix(0, nrow = num_folds, ncol = num_vars, 
                          dimnames = list(paste(1:num_folds), paste(1:num_vars)))

      for(j in 1:num_folds) {

        train_fold    = mtcars[-folds[[j]], ]
        validate_fold = mtcars[ folds[[j]], ]


        best_fit = regsubsets(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, nvmax = 10, method = stepwise)

        for (i in 1:num_vars) {

          pred = predict(best_fit, validate_fold, id = i)

          fold_error[j, i] = rmse(actual = validate_fold$mpg,
                                  predicted = pred)
        }

      }

      cv_error = apply(fold_error, 2, mean)

      par(mfrow=c(1,1))
      plot(cv_error, type = 'l')
      cv_min = which.min(cv_error)
      points(cv_min, cv_error[cv_min], col = "red", cex = 2, pch = 20)

    }

    cv("backward",5)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you include the contents of the error message?

Comment: the error is : Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]) : 
  object 'backward' not found

Comment: I don't have the same error message at all: R tells me that `num_vars` is undefined...

Comment: The "call" in which you try to find the formula for the prediction is completely wrong... and I have no idea on how to fix this particular problem. In your case, maybe a solution would be to pass the formula as an argument of the `cv` function?